# Custom Color User Settings Disappearing

Tags: vb.net, colordialog

So I have a colordialog box that prompts the user to choose a color and it will change the background of the form or textbox whatever. So to get these items to save I had to go into each item with a color change prompt and put something like Me.Twitch.forecolor = my.settings.labelfont well when I go back into the form and make any changes in [Designer] it wipes these settings on each of the items I set them. Is there something I am missing?

```
Private Sub BottomToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BottomToolStripMenuItem.Click

    If ColorDialog2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim bottombackgroundColor As Color = ColorDialog2.Color
        My.Settings.BottomBackgroundColor = bottombackgroundColor

        Me.TabPage1.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.TabPage2.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.TabPage3.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.TabPage4.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.TabPage5.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.Password.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.Remote.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.IE.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.Ticket.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        Me.Helpdesk.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmAbout.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmCheckStatus.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmError.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmGroups.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmLockout.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmNetUser.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmPassGen.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmPreferences.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmServerFind.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmTicketHelper.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmUpdate.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        frmUserSearch.BackColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
End Sub
```

*edit this is the code I am working with and I get this error when I go to open up the main form. Then it just shows my form greyed where the custom colors should be and loading it its also grey, which means I have to manually code buttons and such in so I don't have to go in to the designer code and direct each item to the color setting.

```
Warning 121 The type 'program.My.MySettingsProperty' has no property named 'Settings'.  C:\location\frmMain.Designer.vb 1862    0
```

Comment: Did you call `My.Settings.Save()` after changing them?

Comment: Yea I called the My.settings.save(). I think I might have called it before setting the values though. Under the colorchange btn click event I have my.settings.labelfont = colordialog3.color or something like it. Would the save need to be after that? Because right now its just before it I believe. I dont have the code in front of me right now.

Comment: logic dictates it would be after

Comment: doesn't the naming convention seem odd here `my.settings.labelfont = colordialog3.color`. My brain says `FONT = COLOR`???

Comment: Me.DataGridView1.ForeColor = ColorDialog6.Color is one of the code pieces so its forecolor = color

Comment: Posted the code I am using, any ideas?

Comment: Have you bound the settings to the control properties in the designer?

Comment: No I haven't that's probably the problem I will see if I can find a tutorial on how to bind it. Thanks